# Declaring same property in Child class as in Parent

Tags: java, kotlin

I have stared Kotlin recently and have experience in Java. In Java, we can declare the field with same name as it is in parent. When I do same in `Kotlin` it gives error `name hides member of Super type User`. What am I missing here?

Kotlin

```
open class User(protected var name: String)

class TwitterUser(var name: String) : User(name)
```

Same concept for Java

```
public class A {
    protected String name;
}

public class B extends A {
    String name;
}
```

Comment: Techically doing that is Java *also* hides the member of the super type, Java's compiler just doesn't error out you when that happens... but it probably tosses a warning at you.

Comment: [Unlike Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods), Kotlin requires explicit annotations for overridable members and for overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that you're hiding the implementation of the original property. But there's one possibility to do so anyhow:

```
open class User(protected open var name: String)

class TwitterUser(override var name: String) : User(name)
```

You just have to consider, that this mainly changes the implementation of the property. You will not be able to access `User.name` or `TwitterUser.name` separately. It's just the same.

Comment: With override it says name property is final in User class

Comment: Ohh right. You need to make the `name` open as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change it like,

```
open class ClassParent(name: String) {

}
```

---

```
class ClassChild(name: String) : ClassParent(name) {

}
```

you can use init block, [check details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36254340/kotlin-constructor-with-super-class)

Comment: I know it will work like this. But why the above code gives error?

Comment: it doest override member of parent and you need to override because you are extening parent class so it show this error

Comment: @mallaudin The initial error is because a data class can't have parameters in its primary constructor other than val or var properties. Removing the data keyword lifts this restriction.

Comment: @mallaudin please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/44129826/2826147 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419997/extending-data-class-from-a-sealed-class-in-kotlin

Answer (score 1):

If your superclass already has a `name` property, any subclass will have it automatically, too. Why would you then define it again in that child? It's better to simply define it as a parameter of the constructor without making it another property:

```
open class User(protected var name: String)
//name is not a val/val! simply passed to the constructor as an argument
class TwitterUser(name: String) : User(name)
```

Otherwise, if you really need to override that property, make it open in the parent and override in the child:

```
open class User(protected open var name: String)
class TwitterUser(override var name: String) : User(name)
```